# Shared Inbox Subfolder not visible within VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a routine that worked a few days ago but is hanging up now on `Set SubFolder = oInbox.Folders("ProcessedForms")`.

The inbox has 0 (zero) folders when checked in the Immediate Pane during execution. `?oInbox.Folders.Count`.

I checked Office 365 online and the Outlook App on my computer and there is a subfolder called 'ProcessedForms'.

Here is the full code:

```vba
Private Sub ScrapeOutlook(fileName As String, subject As String)
    Dim intFileNum As Integer
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    
    On Error GoTo ScrapeOutlookErr
    
    'Get the inbox from Outlook
    Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set NS = oApp.Session
    Set objOwner = NS.CreateRecipient("main@mycompany.com")
    objOwner.Resolve

    If objOwner.Resolved Then
        Set oInbox = NS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox)
        Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = oInbox
    End If
    
    If Not TESTING Then Set SubFolder = oInbox.Folders("ProcessedForms")
    
    'Filter the items from the inbox based on the sender
    Set oRestrictItems = oInbox.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = '" & subject & "'")

    intFileNum = FreeFile
    Open fileName For Output As intFileNum
    itemsScraped = 0
    For Each oLatestItem In oRestrictItems
        Print #intFileNum, Replace( _
                            Replace( _
                             Replace( _
                              Replace( _
                               Replace(oLatestItem.Body, ",", "%") _
                              , vbNewLine, ",") _
                             , vbTab, ",") _
                            , ", ,Sent from Mycompany <https://mycompany.com>  ,", "") _
                           , ", ,", ",") & ",Time," & oLatestItem.SentOn
        If Not TESTING Then oLatestItem.UnRead = False
        'If Not TESTING Then oLatestItem.Move SubFolder
        itemsScraped = itemsScraped + 1
    Next oLatestItem
    Close #intFileNum
    
    
ScrapeOutlookExit:
    Exit Sub
    
ScrapeOutlookErr:
    HandleError "NewCustomers.ScrapeOutlook()"
    Resume ScrapeOutlookExit
    Resume
    
End Sub
```

Comment: There surely is no error message "hanging up now". Remove the useless error handling to see.

Comment: I error handle all of my routines out of habit. It has saved my bacon more than once.

Comment: If added as a mailbox through "Account Settings”, see if there is an impact if added as an account with "Add Account". https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetSharedDefaultFolder` for a folder cached in the primary mailbox's OST file contains no subfolders. Either uncheck "Download shared folders" checkbox in the Exchange account properties or open the parent mailbox as a delegate mailbox in the profile so that all folders are available and visible in Outlook.

Comment: Dmitry, thank you for your reply, I turned off the "Download shared folders" option. Unfortunately this did not solve the problem, Outlook was still reporting 0 (zero) subfolders for the Shared Inbox. It still displays it on sidebar in the GUI just fine. Then I turned off cached exchange mode, and again it did not change anything in the folder. I'm at a loss, obviously Outlook can see the folder, but for some reason it is not showing up in the VBA code.

Comment: Did you restart Outlook after changing these options?

Comment: Yes, I sure did. I was hoping that it would work. Nothing seems to help. The oddest part is that it had been work (in the code) before last week.

Comment: If you add the mailbox in question as a delegate mailbox in the account properties, do you see the subfolders?

Comment: This is a shared mailbox through Office 365, we set it up as an account that is not logged into, but one that Shares the mailbox only. This works without the delegate access, I'm not sure how I would do that in this case.

Comment: I meant you can add that mailbox in the primary Exchange account properties in Outlook - Advanced | O;pen these additional mailboxes.

Comment: That solved it, when I checked the settings there I had indeed added it a second time there and that one had the cached exchange mode and the download shared folder options still checked. I unchecked all and viola it was fixed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

With the folders visible in the navigation pane you can try:

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant


Private Sub ScrapeOutlook(fileName As String, subject As String)

    Dim mailBox As Folder
    Dim oInbox As Folder
    Dim subFolder As Folder
    
    'No error handling during debugging.
    
    Set mailBox = Session.Folders("main@mycompany.com")
    Set oInbox = mailBox.Folders("Inbox")
        
    Debug.Print oInbox.Folders.count
    
    If oInbox.Folders.count > 0 Then
        Set subFolder = oInbox.Folders("ProcessedForms")
        Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = subFolder
    Else
        Debug.Print "No subfolders found."
    End If
    
End Sub


Private Sub test_ScrapeOutlook()
    ScrapeOutlook "dummyFilename", "dummySubject"
End Sub
```

Comment: This would partially solve the error that is being raised, but still does not explain why oInbox is reporting 0 subfolders.

Comment: Since the usual fix failed, throwing things at the wall to see what sticks.

Comment: Niton, I used your suggestion in case it goes dark again, simple but effective.